# Passing Window Handles into Variables

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Dim wn, contacts, report As Excel.Window
    Dim windows(1 To 100) As Excel.Window
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1
    For Each wn In Application.windows
        windows(i) = wn
        i = i + 1
    Next wn

    If IsEmailValid(windows(1).Cells(1, 1)) = True Then
        report = windows(1)
        contacts = windows(2)
    Else
        contacts = windows(1)
        report = windows(2)
    End If


End Sub
```

What do you see wrong here? I'm trying my best according to what I know about VBA.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What isn't working? FWIW, you are declaring `wn` and `contacts` as variants.

Answer (score 1):

- You havn't declared your variables correctly (`wn` and `contacts` with be `variant`s).
  Use `Dim wn As Excel.Window, contacts As Excel.Window, report As Excel.Window`
- you need to use `Set` to assign an `object`
  `Set windows(i) = wn`
- The `window` object doesn't have a `Cells` property
  It's not clear what you are actually wanting to achieve, but as a guess you probably want the `Worksheets` collection (of a `workbook`) or possibly `Application.Workbooks` rather than `Application.Windows`